# Error using class_weights parameter with Keras in Multi-Class Classification problem

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nlp

This problem has been asked in other forums and I have tried their variations with no avail: [class_weight for imbalanced data - Keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49806437/class-weight-for-imbalanced-data-keras)

[how to set class-weights for imbalanced classes in keras](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/13490/how-to-set-class-weights-for-imbalanced-classes-in-keras)

However it seems stale as no one has answered the question. Does anyone know how to implement the `class_weight` parameter in Keras when using `categorical_crossentropy`?
I have been trying to use the `class_weight` parameter in Keras but keep getting this error:

> ValueError: Expected `class_weight` to be a dict with keys from 0 to one less than the number of classes, found {'prediction': {0: 1.217169570760731, 1: 5.323420074349443, 2: 0.5023680056130504}

Each sample will be classified either 0, 1, or 2 (softmax). The bias in this dataset is significant. My model using the Keras functional API.

The class_weights were calculated using Sklearn:

```
class_weights = class_weight.compute_class_weight('balanced', np.unique(np.array(y_trn_labels_HB_2_pd['labels'])), y_trn_labels_HB_2_pd['labels'])
class_weight_dict = dict(enumerate(class_weights))
class_weight_dict
```

Here is my last layer:

```
prediction = Dense(3, activation="softmax", name = 'prediction')(x)
```

Here is my model:

```
tf.__version__ = 2.3.0

model = Model(inputs = [sequence_input_head, sequence_input_body, semantic_feat,
             wordOL_feat, avg_subj_feat], outputs = [prediction])
model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy',
             optimizer='adam',
             metrics = ['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

Here is my class_weight parameter:

```
class_weight= {'prediction': {0:1.217169570760731, 1:5.323420074349443, 2:0.5023680056130504} })
```

Here is the full error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-271-e3bb78b84171> in <module>()
     26                                        y_val_2_cat),
     27                     callbacks = [es],
---> 28                     class_weight= {'prediction': class_weights})
     29 
     30 modeled = model.save(os.path.join(save_path, path_model))

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    106   def _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
    107     if not self._in_multi_worker_mode():  # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 108       return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    109 
    110     # Running inside `run_distribute_coordinator` already.

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1061           use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing,
   1062           model=self,
-> 1063           steps_per_execution=self._steps_per_execution)
   1064 
   1065       # Container that configures and calls `tf.keras.Callback`s.

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py in __init__(self, x, y, sample_weight, batch_size, steps_per_epoch, initial_epoch, epochs, shuffle, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, model, steps_per_execution)
   1120     dataset = self._adapter.get_dataset()
   1121     if class_weight:
-> 1122       dataset = dataset.map(_make_class_weight_map_fn(class_weight))
   1123     self._inferred_steps = self._infer_steps(steps_per_epoch, dataset)
   1124 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py in _make_class_weight_map_fn(class_weight)
   1299         "Expected `class_weight` to be a dict with keys from 0 to one less "
   1300         "than the number of classes, found {}").format(class_weight)
-> 1301     raise ValueError(error_msg)
   1302 
   1303   class_weight_tensor = ops.convert_to_tensor_v2(

ValueError: Expected `class_weight` to be a dict with keys from 0 to one less than the number of classes, found {'prediction': {0: 1.217169570760731, 1: 5.323420074349443}}
```

EDIT1:

I tried your suggestion @Prateek Bhatt

```
history = model.fit({'headline': hl_pd_tr, 'articleBody':bd_pd_train, 'semantic': semantic_sim_180_train_x, 'wordOverlap': wrd_OvLp_train_x, 'avg_subjectivity': avg_subj_hb_train_x}, #@param ["model.fit({'headline': hl_pd_tr, 'articleBody':bd_pd_train},", "model.fit({'headline': hl_pd_tr, 'articleBody':bd_pd_train, 'semantic': semantic_x_tr},", "model.fit({'headline': hl_pd_tr, 'articleBody':bd_pd_train, 'semantic': semantic_x_tr, 'wordOverlap': wrd_OvLp_x_tr},", "model.fit({'headline': hl_pd_tr, 'articleBody':bd_pd_train, 'semantic': semantic_x_tr, 'wordOverlap': wrd_OvLp_x_tr, 'avgsubj': avg_subj_x_tr},"] {type:"raw", allow-input: true}
                    {'prediction':y_train_2_cat},
                    epochs=100,
                    batch_size= BATCH__SIZE,
                    shuffle= True,
                    validation_data = ([hl_pd_val, bd_pd_val, semantic_sim_180_val_x, wrd_OvLp_val_x, avg_subj_hb_val_x], y_val_2_cat),
                    callbacks = [es],
                    class_weight= {0:1.217169570760731, 1:5.323420074349443, 2:0.5023680056130504})
```

However, I get this error:

```
ValueError: `class_weight` is only supported for Models with a single output.
```

Full error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-272-bfbab936a723> in <module>()
     26                                        y_val_2_cat),
     27                     callbacks = [es],
---> 28                     class_weight= {0:1.217169570760731, 1:5.323420074349443, 2:0.5023680056130504})
     29 
     30 modeled = model.save(os.path.join(save_path, path_model))

16 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    106   def _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
    107     if not self._in_multi_worker_mode():  # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 108       return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    109 
    110     # Running inside `run_distribute_coordinator` already.

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1061           use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing,
   1062           model=self,
-> 1063           steps_per_execution=self._steps_per_execution)
   1064 
   1065       # Container that configures and calls `tf.keras.Callback`s.

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py in __init__(self, x, y, sample_weight, batch_size, steps_per_epoch, initial_epoch, epochs, shuffle, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, model, steps_per_execution)
   1120     dataset = self._adapter.get_dataset()
   1121     if class_weight:
-> 1122       dataset = dataset.map(_make_class_weight_map_fn(class_weight))
   1123     self._inferred_steps = self._infer_steps(steps_per_epoch, dataset)
   1124 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py in map(self, map_func, num_parallel_calls, deterministic)
   1693     """
   1694     if num_parallel_calls is None:
-> 1695       return MapDataset(self, map_func, preserve_cardinality=True)
   1696     else:
   1697       return ParallelMapDataset(

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py in __init__(self, input_dataset, map_func, use_inter_op_parallelism, preserve_cardinality, use_legacy_function)
   4043         self._transformation_name(),
   4044         dataset=input_dataset,
-> 4045         use_legacy_function=use_legacy_function)
   4046     variant_tensor = gen_dataset_ops.map_dataset(
   4047         input_dataset._variant_tensor,  # pylint: disable=protected-access

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py in __init__(self, func, transformation_name, dataset, input_classes, input_shapes, input_types, input_structure, add_to_graph, use_legacy_function, defun_kwargs)
   3369       with tracking.resource_tracker_scope(resource_tracker):
   3370         # TODO(b/141462134): Switch to using garbage collection.
-> 3371         self._function = wrapper_fn.get_concrete_function()
   3372         if add_to_graph:
   3373           self._function.add_to_graph(ops.get_default_graph())

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in get_concrete_function(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2937     """
   2938     graph_function = self._get_concrete_function_garbage_collected(
-> 2939         *args, **kwargs)
   2940     graph_function._garbage_collector.release()  # pylint: disable=protected-access
   2941     return graph_function

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _get_concrete_function_garbage_collected(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2904       args, kwargs = None, None
   2905     with self._lock:
-> 2906       graph_function, args, kwargs = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
   2907       seen_names = set()
   2908       captured = object_identity.ObjectIdentitySet(

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
   3211 
   3212       self._function_cache.missed.add(call_context_key)
-> 3213       graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
   3214       self._function_cache.primary[cache_key] = graph_function
   3215       return graph_function, args, kwargs

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes)
   3073             arg_names=arg_names,
   3074             override_flat_arg_shapes=override_flat_arg_shapes,
-> 3075             capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
   3076         self._function_attributes,
   3077         function_spec=self.function_spec,

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature, func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies, arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value, override_flat_arg_shapes)
    984         _, original_func = tf_decorator.unwrap(python_func)
    985 
--> 986       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
    987 
    988       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py in wrapper_fn(*args)
   3362           attributes=defun_kwargs)
   3363       def wrapper_fn(*args):  # pylint: disable=missing-docstring
-> 3364         ret = _wrapper_helper(*args)
   3365         ret = structure.to_tensor_list(self._output_structure, ret)
   3366         return [ops.convert_to_tensor(t) for t in ret]

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py in _wrapper_helper(*args)
   3297         nested_args = (nested_args,)
   3298 
-> 3299       ret = autograph.tf_convert(func, ag_ctx)(*nested_args)
   3300       # If `func` returns a list of tensors, `nest.flatten()` and
   3301       # `ops.convert_to_tensor()` would conspire to attempt to stack

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    253       try:
    254         with conversion_ctx:
--> 255           return converted_call(f, args, kwargs, options=options)
    256       except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    257         if hasattr(e, 'ag_error_metadata'):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py in converted_call(f, args, kwargs, caller_fn_scope, options)
    530 
    531   if not options.user_requested and conversion.is_whitelisted(f):
--> 532     return _call_unconverted(f, args, kwargs, options)
    533 
    534   # internal_convert_user_code is for example turned off when issuing a dynamic

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py in _call_unconverted(f, args, kwargs, options, update_cache)
    337 
    338   if kwargs is not None:
--> 339     return f(*args, **kwargs)
    340   return f(*args)
    341 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py in _class_weights_map_fn(*data)
   1310     if nest.is_sequence(y):
   1311       raise ValueError(
-> 1312           "`class_weight` is only supported for Models with a single output.")
   1313 
   1314     if y.shape.rank > 2:

ValueError: `class_weight` is only supported for Models with a single output.
```

Comment: Were you able to solve it ? any solution for it?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a pandas dataframe you can first compute the class_weight parameter using compute_class_weight function and passing the target column like:

```
from sklearn.utils import class_weight 
class_weights = class_weight.compute_class_weight('balanced',np.unique(df['target']),df['target'])
class_weights = dict(enumerate(class_weights))
```

then when fitting you pass the class_weights:

```
history = model.fit(X, Y,epochs=n,class_weight=class_weights)
```

Then make sure you are using one-hot-encoded labels for loss calculation using  categorical_crossentropy. In case you are using the index values use sparse_categorical_crossentropy instead.

Comment: I used the `to_categorical()` like this to get one-hot encoded labels: `y_train_2_cat  =  to_categorical(y_trn_labels_HB_2 , 3)`. I did this to validation set and test set labels.

Answer (score 1):

I see you have 3 classes. In your training set you will have X training samples labelled as class 0, Y training samples labelled as class 1 and Z training samples labelled as class 2.
Now choose from X,Y or Z the largest value. AS an example say X=100, Y=200 and Z=400 samples. So Z=400 is the largest. The weight dictionary can be determined as

```
weight_dict={0:400/100, 1:400/200, 2:400/400}
```

The idea here is that class 2 with 400 samples influences the loss function 4 times more than class 0 and 2 times more than class 1 if you do not use a weights_dict. The weights_dict tries to rebalance this in terms of net impact on the loss function

Comment: I appreciate your input. That is an excellent and intuitive way to go about it. I will be letting my class know if it. Thanks! The issue I’m having is more so to do with Keras accepting the adjusted weights. It doesn’t seem the error will be fixed by anyone soon given the bug page another user linked too here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/40457

Comment: I use class weights all the time for classification. I do not understand the error message since you only have one output. I use tensorflow 2.1.0 .

Comment: Ah. Yeah, I'm using TF 2.1.0, and it seems to be working, but I believe TF is turning it to sample_weights. I get this warning when running it. `WARNING:tensorflow:sample_weight modes were coerced from
  ...
    to  
  ['...']`

Comment: It also doesn't seem to have solve my issue of overfitting, though I may just need to wrangle it a bit more. The dataset I'm working with has a class that is severely under sampled.

Answer (score 0):

Just use class_weights as following:

```
class_weight= {0:1.217169570760731, 1:5.323420074349443, 2:0.5023680056130504}
```

This should be enough.

**Update:**

There is currently a bug in [tensorflow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/40457), try using TF2.1.0

Comment: I get this  'ValueError: `class_weight` is only supported for Models with a single output.' The issue with this error is that I only have one output layer, which is my prediction layer. Does this error mean class_weights does not work for multi-class problems?

Comment: Looks like there is an open bug in tensorflow, I will request to downgrade your tensorflow version to TF2.1.0 and check it out once - https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/40457

Comment: Yeah, hoping someone had a workaround. Issue for me is that downgrading to TF 2.1.0 breaks a major portion of my program.

Comment: oh, yes, then keep an eye for the bug (it has been 6 months since the bug has opened) to get resolved, but as I said in my answer. That is the correct way to use the class_weights. All the best.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and was able to solve it by removing the name in my output layer. In your case, change

```
prediction = Dense(3, activation="softmax", name = 'prediction')(x)
```

to

```
prediction = Dense(3, activation="softmax")(x)
```